# How to keep mule CE 5.3.0 running

Tags: mule, esb

I've created my mule application, and i deploy it on mule ce 5.3.0 my question now is how to keep my server running which means even if i close my CMD (the window where my mule is running) my application keep running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Starting+and+Stopping+Mule+ESB#StartingandStoppingMuleESB-StartingandStoppingMuleViatheCommandLine

**Starting In the Background**

Use the cd command to navigate to the $MULE_HOME/bin directory.
Run the startup script according to the options below.

**Unix:** `./mule start`

**Windows:** `mule.bat start`

Answer (score 0):

To further add on to what Ryan said, you can also install Mule as a service if you're running on Windows. From then you can also configure your Mule server to start up every time your machine boots up.

You can do so using the following command:

```
mule install
```